# Вопросительные слова и вопросительные местоимения

Tags: синонимы

Являются ли словосочетания вопросительные слова и вопросительные местоимения синонимами?

Comment: Зависит от того, считаете ли Вы вопросительные частицы вопросительными словами. Или к вопросительным словам Вы относите только местоимения?

Comment: Вы уверены, что правильно увязываете понятие «синонимы» с этой классификацией?